# Node template engine, like EJS, that doesn't break the HTML template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates

Wondering if there is a templating engine like [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) for [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) that doesn't break the original template HTML through its use of parenthesis.

In EJS, for example, one might use the following to insert specific data into the HTML template:

```
<script>
    window.$data = <%- JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) %>;
</script>
```

Note that the `<%- %>` parenthesis breaks the source HTML file, rendering it useless for quick-fire testing in situations when your want to temporarily drop the use of the EJS parser.

Ignoring disputes of usefulness for a moment, are there any good data-injection libraries for Node which don't break the template? Or, dare I say, for the simple injection of a stringified object into a certain `<script>` element, would a regular expression be out-of-the-question?

Comment: _"would a regular expression be out-of-the-question?"_ Yes, it would.

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), regular expressions are out of the question.

Comment: Have you tried using an external script?

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight unfortunately my use-case is one that requires the data to be injected directly into the HTML.

Comment: @Cerbrus you're conveniently ignoring the prepended "for the simple injection of a stringified object into a certain <script> element". HTML is not a regular language, but that doesn't mean that as the sole author of such a document, I can't apply some regular principles to the desired placeholder of the data. But if I was to run-scared from using RegEx in this instance, do you have any alternative solutions to the problem at hand?

Comment: if the <% %> are what bothers you, afaik you can change these to [% %]: https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Templates#Example 

Alternatively you can look at (for example) swig (https://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/).

Comment: @masch this still breaks the original template file

Answer (score -1):

As you know, EJS would break HTML with it's '<% >' , and the syntax of it looks much like ASP.

If you want a new template which not break HTML, and has a nice coding work flow, you can try this:
Github: https://github.com/eshengsky/saker

It's my personal open source project named Saker, it enables a really compact and expressive syntax which is clean, fast and fun to type.

Here's the preview:

```
<span>@name</span>
<a href="/detail/@id">@title</a>
```